# Is there a way to have `react-scripts` include extra files in the root of the build?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, react-scripts, surge.sh

**My Situation:**

I'm hosting an app created with `create-react-app` on Surge. In order to have Surge let `react-router` handle the routes, I have to add a 200.html to the root, and in order to handle 404s, I have to add a 404.html to the root. The problem is, with `npm run build`, only `index.html` and `favicon.ico` are added to the root of the build directory.

**Possible Solution:**

I can copy other files by making the `build` script in package.json `react-scripts build && cp 200.html 404.html build`.

**Question:**

Is there a better way to have `react-scripts` add extra files to the root of the build, rather than relying on bash scripting in package.json?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer I settled on was to use bash scripts in my package.json as I originally suspected, but I decided to do the file operations in a deploy script instead of the build script, and rename index.html to 200.html instead of copying extra files, [as suggested by the create-react-app docs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#surge);

```
"build": "react-scripts build",
"deploy": "npm run build && mv build/index.html build/200.html && surge build mydomain.com"
```

I think doing the file operation in the deploy script, instead of the build script, is the right solution because that change is unique to the deployment environment, meaning, if I was deploying somewhere other than surge, I might not want to rename the index file.

Still open to other solutions if anyone has a better suggestion.